# English idiomatic proverb that expresses "work makes the doer"?

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

Latvian language (one of the Baltic languages, others being Lithuanian and extinct Prussian language) has proverb (with alliterations) `Darbs dara darītāju`, which can be translated literally into English as `work makes (does) the doer`. My question is - is there the idiomatic expression/proverb with similar meaning in English?

I tried to do the exact-googling of the translated phrase "work makes the doer", but Google gives only pages from Latvia or Lithuania which mention this proverb as distinctly Latvian one with English translation only. I am fan of this proverb and I wonder - is it possible that English have no similar proverb? My guess is that English have such proverb but with different (more English-like) wording. Maybe there is even the Latin roots of this proverb? Or maybe Anglo-Saxon world have such deep cultural advancements (OxCam being the example) and such reliance on education so that such proverb is useless in English speaking cultures which rely on professional education, professionalism as opposite to the in-work skills development and growth of personality?

Growth of skills and personality through the work is the essence of the Latvian proverb. But I guess - this proverb can be applied only to such work in which the growth is possible and necessary be it the development of the motoric skills or the development of intellectual skills. If the work is monotone, without possibility to grow (in such work) then this proverb is useless.

Comment: [Proverbs 12.25:](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/bcc/proverbs-12.html) *"Heaviness in the heart of a man maketh it stoop; But a good work maketh it glad."* [**Kurdish proverb:**](http://www.listofproverbs.com/keywords/judged/) *A man is judged by his work.* Just out of interest, *exactly* what do you understand from your Latvian saying?

Comment: Well - when you start to work, not always you know the details what will you do and how will you achieve the traget, even the target itself can be elusive sometimes. E.g. IT systems development (design and coding) can be such endeavour. You can educate himself a lot but at the end you should start to do and only then the real problems will emerge and only then the search (invention) of the most appropriate solutions can be done. It is coping with unknowns, uncertainties, going path previously not went.

Comment: Education definitely is key, but sometimes it is enough. Or - maybe I have bad eduaction (and society generally have bad education if it celebrates/creates such proverbs?) and that is why I have such outlook? Maybe I don't know what the good education is?

Comment: Something like that is known in computer science/artificial intelligence under the name or "Reinforcement learning" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) - the balance between the exploitation (with more or less sure rewards) and exploration (with possible disrupting discoveries, but huge losses can be possible as well). I guess - RL can be the philosophical concept as well. What is there beyond preferences/utilities/rewards/learning-from-rewards? I guess, it encompass all the life.

Comment: The biblical quotation (Matthew:7:16) "*Ye shall know them by their fruits*" is often adapted to the meaning that I assume you intend: "By their fruits, shalt thou/shall ye know them." (Usually said with negative connotation.)

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you think the Latvian saying means, and you've already got two completely different answers - *neither* of which might match your understanding. One's about repetition improving performance, the other about building "character". And there's also Yoda's "Jedi Knight" dictum ***There is no try. There is only do***, which one could understand as *What counts is **actual works, not aspirations***. Please edit your question to explain *exactly* what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: My father used to say, "If you want a career, get a job." That is, rather than sitting around thinking, "get to work", "do", and the rest (your career) will take care of itself through experience and self development. Perhaps **Work maketh the man.** would work?

Comment: Can you explain which sense of 'make' you're intending? 'constitutes' or 'moulds'?

Comment: My intuition is that "makes" means "develops", "grows", "educates", "trains", "teaches" in this case.

Comment: In French, we have an analog usual expression "prouver le mouvement en marchant" (prove the movement by walking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Making makes the maker" is similarly alliterated if less general, and it and variants occur a few times on the web:

- "Making makes makers" https://www.theupcycler.org/
- "How making makes the maker" http://www.redoakleaves.com/writing.html
- "As the maker makes the made, the making makes the maker" from [At Swim-Two-Birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Swim-Two-Birds)
  https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/thefictionalwoods/great-epigraphs-t897-s10.html

Comment: I am accepting this answer. Although it is very rarely used in English (Google gives less than 20 search results, very, very few by Google standrds), it is used in academic work https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-6160-8.pdf and with reference to Aristotle connected with very noble notion of Poiesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poiesis). So, it may not be the really idiomatic to English, but it has alliteration and it has been used in the translation (by https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kathleen_Haney - professional philosopher) of very important idea by Aristotle.

Comment: So, I guess, I can try to use it in my coat of arms, I have not decided yet.

Comment: @TomR I don't know if you're familiar with the bourbon called Marker's Mark, but if you like bourbon, I offer the following for your coat of arms: *Making Maker's Mark makes makers of Maker's Mark.* Reminds me of this: "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?" Maybe you should make that your motto instead. :-)

Comment: @TomR I don't think I'd want such a logically troubling motto on my coat of arms. Anyone engaged in making is already a maker by definition, and, therefore, cannot be made be made a maker by virtue of making. How about  something more like *Making makes a master maker*? I'm not sure I like it, but at least it's not logically inconsistent. *Practice makes perfect* is growing on me.

Comment: @RichardKayser Well, such recursions (self-references) exist both in logic and nature. Life and cognition are systems making and developing themselves in the process of autopoiesis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autopoiesis which can be implemented by set of autocatalytic reactions. See e.g. the fantastic book by Kauffman, reviewed https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01318-z. It tries to explain the History - unique state in timespace in which we as the complex systems have emerged and from which our unique developments will bring us further.

Comment: @RichardKayser Goedel machines http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/goedelmachine.html are another example or such makers: self-programming programs. Sorry for those references if they are disturbing you, but I would have been happy in the past if I had known these ideas some 5-10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I’ll check out Kaufmann’s book and the other references. Evolution and Goedel have long been interests of mine. Grammar can lead us into all sorts of difficulties. :-)

Answer (score 24):

Probably the following saying comes close to yours:

***[practice makes perfect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/practice-makes-perfect)***:

> said to encourage someone to continue to do something many times, so that they will learn to do it very well.

(Cambridge Dictionary )

Comment: +1 this keeps the pattern of alliteration, which seems to be an integral part of the Latvian proverb

Comment: This answer appears to conflict at least a little with aspects of the OP's question concerning growth, e.g., *Growth of skills and personality through the work is the essence of the Latvian proverb* and *If the work is monotone, without possibility to grow (in such work) then this proverb is useless.*

Comment: @RichardKayser - So sports players never grow their skills through practice?

Comment: I feel, that this is the most appropriate proverb so far, but words "practice" and "perfect" are more specific, more practical than "work"/"doing" and "doer". Just sense. I would be happy to find phrase to put into my coat of arms and that is why it would be better to have more general, more philosophically loaded words.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course they do, but the scale of the answer isn't quite right. It misses the big picture.

Comment: @RichardKayser - Oh, well.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy!

Comment: Well - I guess - this is very connected with the culture. Latvian word "darbs" (job, work, service, engagement) is so loaded with the sense of virtue (e.g. sense, that "work is life", something beyond only to getting earnings for living, those ideas coming from the folk culture, folk songs), that I feel it very hard to find appropriate words in English.

Comment: @HotLicks Meet Jack. :-) February 6, 2016.

Comment: Consider the following variant. "Perfect practice makes perfect" I think that might come a little closer to the original phrase in that it implies that it has to be the "right" kind of practice rather than any sort of practice.

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps **Work maketh the man.** I don't have a reference for this, but I did find references to similar expressions:

> *Careers maketh the man.*
>
> *Habits maketh the man.*
>
> *Clothes maketh the man.*
>
> *Manners maketh the man.*

To my mind, **Work maketh the man** preserves the sense and intent of the OP's rendering of the Latvian proverb, the key being the replacement of **the doer** by **the man**. Implicit in this replacement is that **the man** and **the doer** are one and the same.

Comment: This is the best possible translation, in my opinion.

Comment: @TonyK Yeah, right? It's better than an English idiom (which it easily could be) in the sense that the OP could present and use it as an  accurate rendering in English of the original Latvian proverb. Thanks.

Comment: I've only ever heard this as ["clothes maketh the man"](https://medium.com/@alex_65670/what-is-the-origin-of-clothes-make-the-man-7f75e070bf45), but your suggestion works for me.

Comment: @Rich Yep, that's another one. I've added it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've never noticed it before, but actually _maketh_ is singular. So strictly speaking, _Manners maketh man_ can only mean _Man makes manners_, which sends quite a different message!

Comment: @TonyK Good observation, but as worded, the last one refers to humankind as opposed to animals. It is often used to remind people to be polite, i.e., of the difference between man and animals. There are also references to *Manners maketh the man*, so I've changed it to that. Thanks.

Comment: As @TonyK noted, all of the examples in italics are grammatically incorrect (and undoubtedly the result of substitution into a much older correct version that's tickling the back of my mind but I can't come up with right now).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Your'e right. Perhaps the older version tickling the back of your mind is  *"Manners makyth man*," which was the motto of William of Wykeham [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Wykeham]. The proverb also appeared in the movie *The Kingsman*.

Comment: @RichardKayser, _makyth_ is still third-person singular. But perhaps the rules for agreement used to be different: compare _The wages of sin is death_ (Romans 6:23). It seems that when you said something plural is something singular, you could use the singular (whereas today we must use the plural).

Comment: @TonyK Good point. At least **Work maketh the man** is grammatically correct. :-)

Comment: No; an _idiom_ needs more than 343 hits on Google. The question is 'Is there [an] idiomatic expression/proverb with similar meaning in English?' This isn't an idiom, but a word-for-word translation (and hence off-topic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Several thoughts come to mind. First, in general, I try to provide OPs with they think they *want*, but sometimes I provide them with what I think they *need*. They don't always really know what they want, or don't express what they want clearly. Second, *the perfect is the enemy of the good*. Third, just because you can't find **Work maketh the man** in a book or on the web, doesn't mean it's not a legitimate idiomatic expression. *Work* doesn't literally ***make** the man* -- his parents did that. Those are my views anyway.

Comment: Martin Luther used something like this in *On the Freedom of a Christian* at least to deny it was true, part of his faith versus works argument.  So he said "nullum opus facit artificem" and "Kein Werk macht einen Meister so", often translated as "no work makes the workman"  since Luther makes the reasonable point that the workman makes the work

Comment: @Henry Agree. Luther makes a reasonable point. TonyK said something similar above with regard to *Manners make man*, an example I subsequently deleted. One could just as well say *Man makes manners*, although the two statements don't mean exactly the same thing and the latter is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 9):

**You are what you do, not what you say you'll do.**

On the internet, this proverb is popularly attributed to Carl Jung ([Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/3240-you-are-what-you-do-not-what-you-say-you-ll)). It's not clear that Jung actually said this, since no book is attributed and similarly-phrased sentiments appear in other contexts. For instance, here is Will Durant summarizing (and quoting) Aristotle in his (originally 1926) book *[The Story of Philosophy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Story_of_Philosophy/suLI7RoaBEEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Excellence%20is%20an%20art%20won%20by%20training%20and%20habituation:%20we%20not%20act%20rightly%20because%20we%20have%20virtue%20or%20excellence,%20but%20rather%20have%20these%20because%20we%20have%20acted%20rightly;%20these%20virtues%20are%20formed%20in%20man%20by%20doing%20his%20actions;%20we%20are%20we%20repeatedly%20do.%20Excellence,%20then,%20is%20not%20an%20act%20but%20a%20habit.%E2%80%9D)*.

> Excellence is an art won by training and habituation: we do not act rightly because we have virtue or excellence, but we rather have these because we have acted rightly; "these virtues are formed in man by his doing the actions"; **we are what we repeatedly do**.

The general formulation is baked into many writers' and speakers' repertoire. As a set phrase, **you are what you do** has often been used in the last half-century without attribution to describe learning through activity. Here are a few examples:

> **You are what you do**. What you know is what you do. (*[Task Analysis Methods for Instructional Design](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Task_Analysis_Methods_for_Instructional/MjORAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22you%20are%20what%20you%20do%22&pg=PA157&printsec=frontcover)*, 1998)
>
> **You are what you do**, so make an effort to keep performing in all styles and groups as often as possible. (*[Jazz Pedagogy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Jazz_Pedagogy/7pjNgehSSDIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22you%20are%20what%20you%20do%22)*, 2002)
>
> My dad always says, "**You are what you do**, not what you say." Well, what you do makes me cry at night. You grown-ups say you love us, but I challenge you, please make your actions reflect your words. (*[David Suzuki: The Autobiography](https://www.google.com/books/edition/David_Suzuki/iYmsAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22You%20are%20what%20you%20do%22&pg=PA284&printsec=frontcover)*, 2009)

So "you are what you do" expresses a sentiment similar to "work makes the doer" - you learn through work, through repeated doing.

Answer (score 8):

There are a reasonable number of examples of the expression

- Hard work builds character.

on the internet. See for instance [FrankSonnenbergonline: Hard work is good for your soul](https://www.franksonnenbergonline.com/blog/hard-work-is-good-for-your-soul/).

Comment: This works conceptually but isn't plausible as a replacement for the OP's literal translation *Work makes the doer.*

Comment: The point of your statement being? 'My question is - is there the idiomatic expression/proverb with similar meaning in English?' / 'English idiomatic proverb that **expresses** “work makes the doer” '?

Comment: Okay. Fair point.

Comment: I usually add a period somewhere, change my vote, then delete the period (hopefully the same one).

Answer (score 5):

*"Hard work is its own reward"*

Even if the work is for little or no *monetary* pay-off, it either rewards you with personal growth (skills and/or personality), or a sense of satisfaction / accomplishment.

Answer (score 2):

The German sentence "Übung macht den Meister" is a bit stronger because it begins with "Practice" which is REPEATED work. Meister means a person extremely well-qualified in a certain field. (Maestro in Italian.)

For example, Meisterschaft (the property of being a Meister) means championship. The usual translation "Practice makes perfect" does not do justice to the German sentence.